# Prevent http traffic, and allow https using Automated Certificate management

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, heroku, https

I am using express nodejs module to create the app server. The app is accessibile over both https and http

I want to prevent http endpoint.

I have enabled Automated certificate management. My question is, if I want to use the cert which is generated through acm, how can I use the key and the cert in my nodejs code.

Comment: What does "how can I use the key and the cert in my nodejs code" mean? Can't you just redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an HTTPS server and pass along a private key and certificate like so:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('path/to/key', 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('path/to/cert', 'utf8'),
};

const httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app);
httpsServer.listen(8443);
```

If you don't want to respond to HTTP requests at all, simply don't create an HTTP server. If you want to to forward users to HTTPS instead, you could add something like this:

```
const http = require('http');

app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.secure) {
        const [ host ] = req.headers.host.split(':');
        return res.redirect(`https://${host}:8443${req.url}`);
    }

    return next();
});

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(8000);
```

Or you can handle this at reverse-proxy level. E.g. for Nginx:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

}